# Using REGEX with Java to parse a single line

Tags: java, regex

As I proceed through REGEX issues, I'm amazed at the solutions people have proposed.  Using REGEX in ways I never would have imagined.  Amazing work folks!

I have a file that contains numerous blocks that look like:

```
STID = KATL STNM = 722190 TIME = 141101/2000 
SLAT = 33.62 SLON = -84.35 SELV = 269.0
STIM = 35

SHOW = 12.05 LIFT = 13.39 SWET = 144.43 KINX = 3.80
LCLP = 857.43 PWAT = 9.38 TOTL = 36.21 CAPE = 0.00
LCLT = 270.62 CINS = 0.00 EQLV = -9999.00 LFCT = -9999.00
BRCH = 0.00

PRES TMPC TMWC DWPC THTE DRCT SKNT OMEG
CFRL HGHT
981.70 8.14 4.27 -0.68 293.47 325.20 19.41 0.10
0.00 289.15
```

and I need only parse out:

```
STID = KATL STNM = 722190 TIME = 141101/2000
```

I've included the REGEX in the demo. For your reference, this is what I'm using:

```
STID = [A-Z]{4} STNM = [0-9]* TIME = [0-9]*/[0-9]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sI1kW2/1)

Comment: Am I missing something? This is not a question. Voting to close.

Comment: [Are you looking for this](http://regex101.com/r/sI1kW2/2)

Comment: yep anu, as always, you're the man!

Comment: There is no law that says you have to validate the entire line. In fact that could cause you problems. Grab the line first, use a loose regex (fuzzy) later to break out the parts.  A simple `^STID.*$` in multi-line mode is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
STID *= *[A-Z]{4} *STNM *= [0-9]* *TIME *= *[0-9]*/[0-9]*
```

Thanks to @anubhava